# how can i fixed div something like apple's webpage

Tags: css, html, fixed

how can i make fixed div somethin like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojANM.png

web address: http://store.apple.com/us/buy-ipad/ipad-mini-retina

Comment: You're going to need to at least try writing some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are so-called "sticky notes" and there are plenty of easy-to-implement plugins out there. Have a look at this: http://stickyjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at CSS  `position: fixed;`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

The Javascript plugins that are available basically just add `position:fixed;` and something like `top: 0;` when you scroll down and the top of the browser window reaches that div.